# How to increment fetched data value manually in Laravel or Php?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.8

**Using Laravel 5.8** 
I just want to fetch the work_order_no from table and increment it by 1 and store that value to another variable.

```
$statement = DB::select('select work_order_no from work_order where id = 1');
//$won = $won_id->work_order_no+1;
$nextId = intval($statement[0])+1;
$won = $nextId;
```

It display error - 
Object of class stdClass could not be converted to int

Comment: Try - `intval($statement[0]->work_order_no)+1;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
$statement = DB::table('work_order')->select('work_order_no')->where('id',1)->first();
$nextId = intval($statement->work_order_no) + 1;
$won = $nextId;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code. You need to refer `$statement` using index 0.

```
        $currentId = $statement[0]->work_order_no ;
        $nextId = $currentId + 1;
        echo $nextId;  //prints 2 if $currentId is 1
```